# Azure Static web app - Custom Identity Auth with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-static-web-app, azure-app-registration

I am new to the Azure Static app and struggling to make [Azure AD SSO work with Azure AD app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad). I went through the questions already available on stack overflow but the responses miss the routing config in staticwebapp.config.json file and I feel I am making some mistakes there.

**Active Directory registration**
[image]
[image: Supported A/c types and flow settings]
[image: Secrets]

**staticwebapp.config**
[image]

**Azure Static web app configuration**
[image]

Now when I try to login using the URL https://black-flower-007ce3a10.2.azurestaticapps.net/login, it gets redirected to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fblack-flower-007ce3a10.2.azurestaticapps.net%2f.auth%2flogin%2faad%2fcallback&client_id=&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=91a9c801d3dd4a85b274fecdeb713958_20221109234404&state=redir%3d%252F.auth%252Fcomplete&sso_nonce=&client-request-id=
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the **API permissions of the Azure AD Application are not consented** by the Global Admin like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, sign-in with **`Global Admin account`** and grant the **admin consent** for the API permissions like below:

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can also sign-in with **`Global Admin`** credentials and **Accept** the consent on behalf of organization like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

After doing the above setting, when I hit the **`Authorize URL`** and signed in with user credentials, I am able to get the response successfully like below:

[image]

**If you want to allow users to consent to the Application, try the below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Application -> User Settings -> Go to Consent and permissions*

[image]

Comment: thanks, The problem was 'Grant admin consent'